# Keep chart.js doughnut with fixed width and height centered in container

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js, pie-chart

I am using the aurelia plugin for chart js and have a dynamic Doughnut chart.  I have set responsive to false for the chart as I would like it to remain a fixed width and height throughout all screen/device sizes.  However, I cannot keep the chart centered as the canvas element overflows its container.  If I set a max-width on the canvas element...it keeps the chart centered but completely distorts the doughnut by squishing it.  See images:

Here is the chart at a large screen size, rendering properly:

[image]

As I decrease the viewport, the canvas element overflows its container, keeping the chart centered in the 'canvas' element but it's overflowing its container so it's not centered how it should be:

[image]

If I set a max-width on the canvas, it keeps the chart centered but seriously distorts the doughnut:

[image]

I cannot use the responsive option for chart.js doughnut as this causes it to become way too small at certain screen sizes.  How can I just keep this fixed width and height that I have while keeping the chart centered properly.  Here's my chart.js options:

```
        this.doughnutOptions = {
            cutoutPercentage: 80,
            responsive: false,
            tooltips: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
```

And how I'm rendering the chart with Aurelia...

```
<chart id="dynamic-doughnut-chart" type="doughnut" should-update="true" throttle="2000" data.bind="dynamicDoughnutData" native-options.bind="doughnutOptions"></chart>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried, as stupid as it sounds, to put a div around it and make the div your set width and height to contain the canvas?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this? @JordanBarber?

Answer (score 4):

As found here, [Chart.js Doughnut Chart Sizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50651940/chart-js-doughnut-chart-sizing), the new ChartJS standard is `aspectRatio: 2`, so you need to set `aspectRatio: 1` on `options` object.