# Chart.js Doughnut Chart Sizing

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

I'm using [ng2-charts](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts) in an Angular project. I have two versions of the project. The current production version is old and using an old version of ng2-charts (and, by extension, chart.js). I'm working on upgrading the project. I've run across something weird though.

I'm using the doughnut chart from ng2-charts, and the default size that the chart loads at in the old version is a 1:1 ratio:

[image]

You can see that it loads with a height and width of 240px. The weird thing is that in the newer version of ng2-charts/chart.js, the width to height ratio is 2:1:

[image]

I am using the same options in the new version, the same setup, etc. The only difference is the package version.

Is there a setting for Chart.js that would help me fix it? I like the size of the old chart, but can't get the new one to do that without allowing the `canvas` of the chart to bleed outside my component, which for obvious reasons I don't want.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Set `aspectRatio: 1` in the `options` object provided to Chart.js to get what you're looking for. The default `aspectRatio` is 2 in the current version (there was a time when it was 1, but that was reverted to improve backwards compatibility). As you might guess, setting it to .5 causes the `height` of the element to be double that of the width.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rvaEvZ) (this pen taken from [this](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/5432) Github issue)

Comment: This Codepen is constantly refreshing every second, not seen that before. Any ideas?